# call interactive function from elisp code without worrying about arguments

Tags: interactive, ispell

So, I want to do `(ispell-change-dictionary)` inside a function I'm writing, but doing a test throws this error:

```
(wrong-number-of-arguments #[(dict &optional arg)
```

I was told that `M-x` calls the function without arguments. Well, I did the same but for me an error happens. Weird.

I just want to allow the user to select a dictionary without hard-coding the list of dictionaries, showing what's available just as `M-x ispell-change-dictionary RET` does.

Comment: Using `M-x` calls the function *interactively*, and the function's `interactive` form is then used to gather the necessary argument values (possibly prompting the user for some of the values).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to call an interactive function from within elisp, but
call it as if you invoked it interactively (e.g., via `M-x some-command`), you can wrap it in the `call-interactively` function.

The first part of the docstring reads:

> `(call-interactively FUNCTION &optional RECORD-FLAG KEYS)`
>
> Call `FUNCTION`, providing args according to its interactive
>   calling specs.  Return the value `FUNCTION` returns.  The function
>   contains a specification of how to do the argument reading.  In
>   the case of user-defined functions, this is specified by placing a
>   call to the function `interactive` at the top level of the
>   function body.  See `interactive`.

So, in your case, you can use  `(call-interactively #'ispell-change-dictionary)` within the body of your function.